# get ansible_fqdn from all hosts in a group

Tags: ansible, fqdn

I am trying to get the `ansible_fqdn` from all hosts in a group with something in a template with something like this

```
{% for host in  groups.all %}
{{ hostvars[host].ansible_fqdn }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or using:

```
{% for host in query('inventory_hostnames', target) | map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname') %}
{{ hostvars[host].ansible_fqdn }}
{% endfor %}
```

In all cases I get:

```
"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_fqdn'"
```

I do notice that if I just "print/write":

```
{{ hostvars[host] }}
```

The  `ansible_fqdn` is within `facter_networking`, but also trying:

```
{{ hostvars[host][facter_networking].fqdn }}
```

or

```
{{ hostvars[host][facter_networking].fqdn }}
```

I get:

```
fatal: [10.25.176.10]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object has no element  {
'domain': 'test-x',
'fqdn': 'TEST-X.example.org',
'hostname': 'TEST-X',
'interfaces': {
    'ens192': {
        'bindings': [{
            'address': '10.25.176.10',
            'netmask': '255.255.254.0',
            'network': '10.25.176.0'
        }, {
            'address': '10.25.177.226',
            'netmask': '255.255.252.0',
            'network': '10.25.176.0'
        }],
        'ip': '10.25.176.10',
        'mac': '00:50:56:8f:ce:ca',
        'mtu': 1500,
        'netmask': '255.255.254.0',
        'network': '10.25.176.0'
    },
    'lo': {
        'bindings': [{
            'address': '127.0.0.1',
            'netmask': '255.0.0.0',
            'network': '127.0.0.0'
        }],
        'ip': '127.0.0.1',
        'mtu': 65536,
        'netmask': '255.0.0.0',
        'network': '127.0.0.0'
    }
},
'ip': '10.25.176.10',
'mac': '00:50:56:8f:ce:ca',
'mtu': 1500,
'netmask': '255.255.254.0',
'network': '10.25.176.0',
'primary': 'ens192'
}
}
```

If I use:

```
{{ hostvars[host].facter_networking }}
```

I get:

```
"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'facter_networking'
```

The data is there but any idea about how could I extract it?

This is the playbook:

```
- name: Gathering info
  action: setup

- name: Create .pgpass
  template:
    src: pgpass.j2
    dest: /home/postgres/.pgpass
    owner: postgres
    group: postgres
    mode: 0600
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you gathering facts for "all" hosts of your inventory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ansible facts gathered for the hosts can be accessed from within the `ansible_facts` dictionary. So, to access a host's `fqdn`, you would have to access `hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['fqdn']`.

Since we are iterating over `groups['all']`, just make sure that the gather facts task is running on `- hosts: all` as well.

So, using the above method, the template could look like this:

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_facts']['fqdn'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that the `ansible_` prefix is not required, i.e. `fqdn` instead of `ansible_fqdn`.

Comment: Thanks, the problem I was passing the `-l` (limit), after calling the playbook removing it worked out, wondering if there is a way to limit the playbook so some hosts but still fetching facts from all hosts?

Comment: There is an option to enable [fact caching](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts). Not tested, but with cached facts, we might be able to use them with the limit option.